# Why didn't Brom tell Eragon this information earlier?

Tags: inheritance-cycle

In the book Brisingr, Eragon finds out that

> Brom is his father.

Why wouldn't Brom tell Eragon this information earlier. Oromis provides a reason why Brom didn't tell Eragon this but I think it was something else.

Answer (score 5):

As you mentioned in your question, Oromis speculates on the reason for Brom withholding the information.

> "I cannot pretend to know the reasons for everything Brom did, Eragon.
>  However, of this much I am confident: Brom wanted nothing more than to
>  name you his son and to raise you, but he dared not reveal that you
>  were related, lest the Empire should find out and try to hurt him
>  through you. His prudence was warranted too. Look how Galbatorix
>  strove to capture your cousin so that he could use Roran to force you
>  to surrender."
>
>
>  "Brom  could  have  told  my  uncle," Eragon protested. "Garrow
>  wouldn’t have betrayed Brom to the Empire."
>
>
>  "Think, Eragon. If you had been living with Brom, and if word of
>  Brom’s survival had reached the ears of Galbatorix’s spies, you both
>  would have had to flee Carvahall for fear of your lives. By keeping
>  the truth hidden from you, Brom hoped to protect you from those
>  dangers."

Though he admits he's making an educated guess, I don't see any reason to doubt Oromis' theory. The explanation makes sense and fits with Brom's character. There's also no evidence in the text to suggest an ulterior motive on Brom's part.